# Spring @Value annotation and setter injection difference

Tags: java, spring

When I am setting a value using  @Value annotation from a property file, its not working, whereas setting using setter injection works.

my properties file like this.

```
app.work.dir=file:${user.home}/WORK
```

class file like below.

```
@Value("#{configProperties['app.work.dir']}")
private String workdir;
```

and this is my xml setting.

```
<util:properties id="configProperties" location="classpath:config.properties" />
```

when use setter injection like below then it works fine.

```
<bean id="sampleService" class="aaa.SampleService">
    <property name="workdir" value="${app.work.dir}" />
</bean>
```

I'm not sure why and if possible i want to use @Value annotation.

please refer to junit test case below.

xml configulation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:testconfig.properties" />
    <util:properties id="sampleProperties" location="classpath:testconfig.properties" />

    <bean id="exampleA" class="aa.sample.SampleA" />

    <bean id="sampleB" class="aa.sample.SampleB" >
        <property name="workdir" value="${work.dir}" />
        <property name="tempdir" value="${work.dir.test}" />
        <property name="aaa" value="${aaa}" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

sample service class:

package aa.sample;

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SampleA {

    @Value("#{sampleProperties['work.dir']}")
    private String workdir;
    @Value("#{sampleProperties['work.dir.test']}")
    private String tempdir;
    @Value("#{sampleProperties['aaa']}")
    private String aaa;

    //getter setter deleted

}
```

properties file:

```
work.dir=file:${user.home}/WORK
work.dir.test=${work.dir}/TEST
aaa=bbb
```

and junit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "/testcontext.xml" })
public class ExampleTest {

    @Inject
    private SampleA sampleA;

    @Inject
    private SampleB sampleB;

    @Test
    public void testValueAnnotation() {

        assertThat(sampleA.getAaa(), is("bbb"));//ok
        String tempdir = sampleA.getTempdir();
        String workdir = sampleA.getWorkdir();
        assertFalse("[sampleA] temp dir should not have ${work.dir}", tempdir.indexOf("${work.dir}") >= 0);//ng
        assertFalse("[sampleA] workdir dir should not have ${user.home}", workdir.indexOf("${user.home}") >= 0);//ng
    }


}
```

Comment: when use @Value can get file:{user.home}/WORK but use setter injection can get file:/Users/hoge/WORK  .

Comment: Post your full configuration. Do you have a property resolver? What is the expected result?

Comment: added full configuration please refer to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bean generated by

```
<util:properties id="sampleProperties" location="classpath:spring.properties" />
```

basically translates to a map. This notation

```
@Value("#{sampleProperties['work.dir']}")
```

requests one of its valued mapped with the key `work.dir`. There's no property resolution that occurs on the value returned. It's taken literally.

This, on the other hand,

```
<property name="tempdir" value="${work.dir.test}" />
```

requests a property, called `work.dir.test` which can be recursively resolved.

Comment: thank you for your answer. your answer means @Value annotation can not support recursive property setting ?

Comment: @rakuraku No, it can. Use `@Value("${work.dir}")` and it will behave the same as the XML example you have. It's the `#{...}` notation that doesn't do property resolution.